# Why do the private variables in a factory not get updated?

Tags: angularjs

I have an interval in a factory that calls a function that fetches the latest exchange rates.

There will be some calculations that will need to be updated everytime the exchange rates are updated.

So I was just going to re-calculate the values everytime within $http.get.success.

However, the local variables don't seem to get updated. I created a simple jsfiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/magician11/37msdsry/2/

```
app.factory('testFactory', function(){
var number1 = 0, number2 = 0;

var getLatestExchangeRates = function() {

    $http.get('https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/IDR/')
    .success(function(response) {
        blockchainInfoExchangeRates.IDR = response.last;
    });

    printValues();
};

var printValues = function() {

    console.log('number1: ' + number1);             
    console.log('number2: ' + number2);
};

$interval(getLatestExchangeRates, 60000);
getLatestExchangeRates();
```

Why doesn't number1 print out the updated value?

Comment: Because the values are not updated anywhere? The only thing the code modifies is `blockchainInfoExchangeRates.IDR`. Why would `number1` and `number2` change?

Comment: By changing the data from the controller this factory is injected to (bound to an input box), number1 and number2 won't get updated?

Comment: You're not showing what your factory returns, and you're not showing how the numbers are bound to fields in a view. We can't guess these parts. Show the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

After returning from factory method, number1 property holds a value at the time the factory returned.

That is why number1 never get's updated.

To get access to the private variable, you need to return a function, which would capture a reference to original private variables, just like it already works with printValues function:

```
return {
    getValues : function() { return {number1 : number1, number2: number2 }; }
    printValues: printValues
};
```

This is how you can use it now:

```
console.log($scope.testFactory.getValues().number1);

$scope.currentNumbers = $scope.testFactory.getValues();
...
<p>{{currentNumbers.number1}}</p>
```